# Import users from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0

I am using JOOMLA version 3.2, I Want to import the users in my Joomla 3 website from another one website which is developed by Joomla 1.5, Is it possible to do it? Any free extensions available for this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to enable PHP XSL Extensions in the server to be able to successfully import users from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.xx. To do this,

```
1. The PHP XSL library needs to be compiled.
2. The compiled PHP Extension can then be loaded in a custom php.ini under your DocumentRoot.
3. The XSL Extension requires libXML -- does your existing PHP installation have it?
```

You can enable PHP XSL Extension via Easyapache, or if or shared hosting, open PHP Settings and activate xls ticking its button. The same can also be executed by editing php.ini file, and editing xls extension from Off to On. 
All the best!